# Ruby on Rails 5: double association between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, many-to-one, fields-for, accepts-nested-attributes

I've been working on this issue for a few days now, and the other Stack Overflow posts I've looked at are either really old, or not quite what I need.

### **Problem:**

There are three models involved:

**Trip** - represents a trip and its associated information, NOTE: does not include any information about crew members.

**Milestone** - represents an action taken on a trip (for the purposes of this problem, when a crew member embarks or disembarks).

**CrewMember** - represents a single crew member on the trip, each crew member has an embark and disembark Milestone which may be shared with other crew members if they embark or disembark at the same place. **CrewMembers are linked to Milestones by both their embark_milestone_id and disembark_milestone_id.**

Now I'm working on a form where a user can edit all the information from a trip, this includes which CrewMembers are present on the trip, what their roles are, and where they get embark/disembark. The trip is being edited, so the whole page is wrapped in a form_for builder.

The segment of the page that edits CrewMembers is wrapped in a fields_for builder. The Trips model is configured to accept nested attributes for the CrewMember model. The number of crew members is variable, and each needs to have their information edited separately (so I can't use select_tags as far as I know). This works fine to display the crew members in the view, but does not work when I actually try to update, because CrewMembers are associated with Milestones through both embark_milestone_id and disembark_milestone_id instead of just milestone_id.

### Question:

So with all that in mind, is there a way to 'teach' rails to recognize CrewMembers through Milestones from a trip form by either embark_milestone_id, disembark_milestone_id or preferably both?

My impression is that this is not the 'Rails' way of doing something like this, but I wanted to post the idea to the community before moving to a messier work-around.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

### Model Code as Requested:

```
class CrewMember < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :guide
  belongs_to :milestone
end

class Trip < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :launch_slot, required: true
  has_many :milestones
  has_many :places, through: :milestones
  has_many :crew_members, through: :milestones, foreign_key: embark_milestone_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :milestones
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :crew_members
end

class Milestone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :place

  has_many :crew_members
end
```

Comment: can you show us the models code ?

Comment: 'Works fine to display the crew members in the view, but does not work when I actually try to update' - Could show us your view and how your updating at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want two `belongs_to` relationships from CrewMember to Milestone. You’ll need to give these relationships different names, and then override the default class name using the `class_name` option (see [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)):

```ruby
class CrewMember < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :guide
  belongs_to :embark_milestone, class_name: :Milestone
  belongs_to :disembark_milestone, class_name: :Milestone

end
```

Then from the Milestone class you’ll need to define two `has_many` relationships back to the CrewMember class. This time you’ll also need to specify the foreign_key, as that can’t be inferred either:

```ruby
class Milestone < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :trip

  has_many :embarking_crew_members, class_name: :CrewMember,
    foreign_key: :embark_milestone_id
  has_many :disembarking_crew_members, class_name: :CrewMember, 
    foreign_key: :disembark_milestone_id

end
```

Your next question then is how to get a collection of allCrewMembers from the Trip model. You suggested that you'd want to return either crew members connected via the `embark_milestone_id` OR the `disembark_milestone_id`. There’s no straightforward way of doing this – you'd have to write your own method which both the `embarking_crew_members` and `disembarking_crew_members` relationships, joins them together, and then removes any duplicates. However, is it really possible to have a CrewMember who disembarks but didn't embark? ;-)